# Find dBm and watts of the attenuator?

Tags: power-electronics, math

The question says "A signal of 40 dBm is passed through the first attenuator. The first attenuator has a gain of 1. The second attenuator has 20 dB output. Find the dBm and watts

This is what I tried doing:

40 dBm = 10*log(Pout/1mWatt)

Pout = 10 W

10 W/Pin = 1 gain

Pin = 10 W

20 = 10*log(Pout2/10 W)

Pout2 = 1000 W

Pout2 = 10*log(1000 W/.001 W) = 60 dBm

is what I did correct?

Comment: What do you understand by the term "attenuator" - specifically, what are the bounds on its gain?

Comment: You got more power out of an attenuator than you put in ... hmmm ... can you send me one of those ... ? :)

Comment: An attenuator with a positive gain?

Comment: "The second attenuator has 20 dB output" doesn't that define Pout2? If that 20dBm? If not 20 dB with respect to what? 20dB attenuation? You can't just say 20dB output.

Comment: @brhans: I've got some of those too, right next to my jar of negative resistors I keep out at my unicorn ranch.

Comment: @OlinLathrop is your unicorn ranch running off the grid on its cold-fusion reactor?

Comment: @BrianDrummond I'm going to go hide in shame, I didn't know what an attenuator was but I do know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to convert from dB to Watts and back again.  This can be done, and is in fact easier, to do everything in dB.  You can then convert to Watts at the end.

However, the question is ambiguous, at least as you have transcribed it.  It is not clear what *"The second attenuator has 20 dB output"* is supposed to mean.  If it's a attenuator, then presumably it's passive.  In that case it can't increase the power coming out relative to what is coming in.  It can't have a gain of 20 dB.  Perhaps it is supposed to say a gain of -20 dB, or maybe it is supposed to say that the output is at 20 dBm, but just "20 dB output" in this context makes no sense.

Note that the first "attenuator" does nothing, since it has a gain of 1, which can also be expressed as 0 dB.  Let's assume the second attenuator actually has a gain of -20 dB.  The output signal is therefore:

(40 dBm) + (0 dB) + (-20 dB) = 20 dBm = 100 mW

Comment: @Simon: Yes, fixed.